# Difference between a Part and a Detail

Tags: terminology

I'm not sure I'm in the right place for this, if not, Apologies.

In my education material under Construction Steel, in its application it lists Masking Details.

Under Tool Steel it list an application as Maskin Parts.

But nowhere I look or ask have I been able to find an answer as to the difference in meaning between Part and Detail has here. 
And from my other education material the word 'detail' is used for (as far as I can confirm) anything on a schematic and I've never encountered the word 'part' in such connotation. On the other hand in the workshop I hear the word 'detail' used to refer to anything made.

Oh, and the language I'm taking the education in is Swedish, so I've translated the terms.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard both terms used and in my experience have different meanings depending on the context and industry. It's nothing to get hung up on.

Yes, sometimes a "detail" can refer to an entire part and it's typically an item that goes into an assembly. Some assembly drawings will actually refer to the parts that make the assembly as "details".

So, it's pretty common in a shop to refer to parts as details as they typically are "details". **Therefore "detail" and "part" are synonymous.**

**Also, a "detail" can be literal**. Commonly used in architecture/construction which would refer to how a particular area or elements come together with each aspect being defined with the "detail".

*It is used as both a noun and verb*

If drafting, there are "detail" views which are typically used to "zoom" on more complex areas to show features that need to be described.